# SQL join with different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to inner join TableA and TableB using columns `invoice` and `nr`.
the column `nr` has different formats on both tables
in TableA. Column `nr` always has three positions or an empty value.
in TableB, Column nr has 1 or 2 positions.

[image]

[image]

For example, if we check for invoice= 322 and invoice= 234 on both tables.
I must fill in "0" or "00" on TableB to equal the number of positions.

and for TableA, when `nr` is a null or empty value, I want to replace it by 0
For example, if we check invoice=123 and invoice=567 on both tables.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: *"column B has different formats on both tables in TableA"* Then they aren't the same value. Fix your design first, then worry about the joining. Clearly you should be sorting out your referential integrity here and implementing primary and foreign keys.

Comment: I suppose that you mean column `nr` when you say column `B` ? They are not of the same datatype, thus you cannot join on that column safely. It's that simple. Fix the design first, and this problem will be non existing anymore, nor any problems that you will still come to face in the future when you keep this faulty design

Comment: One `workaround` for your design problem would be to convert column `nr` from `tableA` to int before you join, like `join TableB b on convert(int, a.nr) = b.nr` . But this is not a safe workaround, fixing the design is the best solution

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does your join look like currently?  Please take an initial crack at the query and show us what specifically is tripping you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TableA's nr column is probably a VARCHAR instead of a number type.
So CAST or CONVERT it to the same type as TableB.nr (probably INT)

And use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) or [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) to change the NULL's to 0

```
SELECT 
  a.invoice
, b.nr
, a.name
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
  ON b.invoice = a.invoice 
 AND b.nr = ISNULL(CAST(a.nr AS INT), 0)
```

Comment: @hana  Thanks. Notice the update to deal with the NULL's. Empty strings get casted to 0 anyway.